# Where can I find the built-in data types for Python 3?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, types, built-in

This is probably a really dumb question, but I'm new to programming and I want to understand how the in-built classes and their methods work. I've tried searching for builtins on my computer (I can't find it for some strange reason -- but perhaps it's that obvious and I just can't find it.), or is there something a little more low level going on there that I'm unaware of?

If it is just in a builtin python module and I'm dumb, where can this be found?

Thanks.

Comment: By... reading the doc ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: This doesn't contain what I was looking for.

Comment: Its unclear what you are looking for, as apparently it is not documentation ... please be more specific

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the way it works itself. So they're not defined in the library? I assumed that they were imported like a module through it. I just want to see the source of how they're defined so I can see how the attributes of the classes and their methods.

Answer (score 1):

The most common implementation of Python is actually written in C. (Thus it is usually called CPython... not to be confused with Cython.) Thus, built in functions and classes are most frequently written in C. [An example.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Modules/_io/clinic/stringio.c.h) As such, it's hard to get more detailed than the documentation without delving a great deal more thoroughly into the internals of Python and a language that you likely don't need or want to know at this point. The [stdtypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) documentation for Python 3 should include all of the detail you need for working with the language.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thought this may have been the case. So it'd be a lot of effort just to understand little more at the end of it?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Oh, you'd understand a *lot*--language implementations are fun. :) However, in terms of using Python for practical purposes, you'll gain little.

Comment: Fair enough! You got where I was going with my question, though! :)